# Error installing postgis for YugabyteDB in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

I tried to install postgis plugin by following the directions in the docs  [Yb Version 2.14.0.0 , Ubuntu 22.04] . What am I missing?

```
yugabyte=# CREATE EXTENSION postgis;
WARNING:  AbortSubTransaction while in DEFAULT state
WARNING:  AbortSubTransaction while in ABORT state
WARNING:  AbortSubTransaction while in ABORT state
WARNING:  AbortSubTransaction while in ABORT state
ERROR:  Illegal state: Set active sub transaction 2, when not transaction is running
ERROR:  Illegal state: Rollback sub transaction 2, when not transaction is running
ERROR:  Illegal state: Rollback sub transaction 2, when not transaction is running
ERROR:  Illegal state: Rollback sub transaction 2, when not transaction is running
ERROR:  Illegal state: Rollback sub transaction 2, when not transaction is running
PANIC:  ERRORDATA_STACK_SIZE exceeded
server closed the connection unexpectedly
    This probably means the server terminated abnormally
    before or while processing the request.
The connection to the server was lost. Attempting reset: Succeeded.
```

Found a relevant github issue here https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/13359

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here are the steps that were successful for another user:

1. (Disabled pg audit) sed -ie '/-- Check that pgaudit is disabled or
   not installed/,+18d'
   /home/yugabyte/postgres/share/extension/postgis--3.2.1.sql
2. Downgraded Ubuntu from 22.04 and 20.04 and 18 now and repeated the
   step1
3. Now the GLIBC_2.27 with Ubuntu 18.
4. Rerun the `postinstall.sh` otherwise it's not working.

It's working now and tested with a couple of GIS data types.